# How to extract the UID info using grep?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get the user name from `/proc/*/status` but

```
cat $i/status|grep "^Uid"|awk '{printf "%4s",$2}'
```

only display the number, instead of that I need the name, if it's `0` I need to display root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Use `getent` for resolving UID to username:

```
getent passwd `grep "^Uid" /proc/$i/status |awk '{printf "%4s",$2}'`| cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Thanks but that also prints the number, how do i do it to just print the username?

Comment: prints only username for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
% getent passwd $(grep -oP '^Uid:\s*\K\d+' /proc/$$/status) | cut -d: -f1
```

change `$$` (current shell processus pid)

Comment: Did you read the question? He wants the user name, not the UID.

Comment: The title is just a summary. The actual question is in the text. You have to read the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {uid[$3]=$1; next} /^Uid:/ {print uid[$2]}' FS=":" /etc/passwd FS="[ \t]+" /proc/1665/status
root
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR {         # /etc/passwd
    uid[$3]=$1    # an array with key=uid, value=username
    next
} 
/^Uid:/ {         # /proc/.../status record startin with Uid
    print uid[$2] # print username from array where uid matches
}
```